# icons displayed as chinese characters in starship

Tags: starship

i am expericing a very bizarre thing that has never occured before:

one of the icons in the starship prompts is displayed as Chinese.

i have checked my locale settings and everything is correct. i also switched multiple nerdy fonts, it is still there.
[image]